# Find the specific number of specific value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, parameters

I have to show the specific value in a table that I have to get that from user, for example user write 2 and 'toilet paper' than I have to show the second date of toilet paper in my table:

I wrote this but I know I doesn't work:

```
CREATE PROC BuyCount(@NInput INT,
                    @TitleInput nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RecordItemCount INT
SET @RecordItemCount = (SELECT COUNT(FID) FROM Buy_tbl WHERE Bname = @TitleInput)

IF (@Input <= @RecordItemCount)
    BEGIN
        SELECT BuyDate , @Input  
        FROM Buy_tbl 
        WHERE Bname = @TitleInput AND ...
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'Out of range'
        SELECT BuyDate , @Input  
        FROM Buy_tbl 
        WHERE Bname = @TitleInput
    END
END
```

PS: Also I should mention, If the number was out of range it returns the last value of the buy items

Comment: What is the question? How you know that your query didn't work?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "not working properly"? What you mean by "second date of toilet paper"?

Comment: i have table that has different date of buying stuff, user enter 2 and toilet paper, then i have to return the second times that toilet paper was bought in the table

Answer (score 0):

Following query should work in both the scenarios

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT BuyDate
        ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY BuyDate) rn
        ,count(*) OVER () ct
    FROM Buy_tbl
    WHERE Bname = @TitleInput
    )
SELECT TOP 1 BuyDate
    ,@Input
FROM cte
WHERE rn = @Input
    OR rn = ct
   ORDER BY BuyDate
```

[Example Demo](https://rextester.com/RPU28303)

Comment: could u please explain what does this "count(*) OVER () ct" do?

Comment: row_number() will assign a running number (1,2,3...n) based on BuyDate, and count() will give the count of all the records.

Comment: I know but what OVER() do there

Comment: over() is used for partitioning, if you need to to use any aggregate function without group by, you can do it using OVER()

Comment: check this link, you will find few examples and more about OVER() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: yeah i understad but when i delete this line my last condition that i mention about being out of range doesnt work, i dont get it

Comment: You should not be deleting it, it is used for the last condition only if @input doesnot match where rn = ct will return the last record having the max date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226807/discussion-between-psk-and-sara-moradi).